# count child elements of a parent element using jquery

Tags: jquery

hi I am using this code below to count the img elements inside the div gallery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var numimg=$("#gallery > img").size();

 document.write(numimg);
</script>

<div class="slide" id="gallery">
             <img src="images/6.jpg"/>
             <img src="images/7.jpg"/>
            <img src="images/8.jpg"/>
                        <img src="images/9.jpg"/>
                        <img src="images/10.jpg"/>
            <img src="images/11.jpg"/>
    </div>
```

the value i am recieving is 0, when there are 6 img elements. I need to get real number of child elements within div element. Can anybody help me out please.

Comment: FYI `.size()` was deprecated in jQuery 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

**Replace**

```
$("#gallery > img").size();
```

**with**

```
$("#gallery > img").length;
```

and wrap code inside document.ready as below.

```
$(function(){
    $("#gallery > img").length;
});
```

Comment: Actually they are _direct_ children.

Comment: It will count all 6 direct children.

Comment: `$("#gallery > img").size();` is fine. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/a3Enm/. The real problem is that it's not being called when the images exist on the page yet.

Comment: Because - before you partially corrected it - your answer was giving misinformation; you're still suggesting a selector change for no particular reason.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems, your code needs to be inside the dom ready handler, after dom ready don't use `document.write`, and use the `length` property to get the number of child elements

```
jQuery(function(){
    var numimg=$("#gallery > img").length;
    $('body').append(numimg)
})
```

If you want to add the count to specific location of the page, then you can add a place holder element and then add the content to it

```
<span id="imgcount"></span>
<div class="slide" id="gallery">
    <img src="images/6.jpg"/>
    <img src="images/7.jpg"/>
    <img src="images/8.jpg"/>
    <img src="images/9.jpg"/>
    <img src="images/10.jpg"/>
    <img src="images/11.jpg"/>
</div>
```

then

```
jQuery(function(){
    var numimg=$("#gallery > img").length;
    $('#imgcount').html(numimg)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tDWF8/%27)

Comment: A bundle of thanks Arun for this detailed explanation. and dipesh thanks as well

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you need to do [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/aVva7/)

```
$(function(){
var c = $('#gallery  img').length;
$('#imgcount').html(c);
});
```